# How to manage maven depend project from Artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

Inside a Parent project i have multiple project and take this simple example **Project common-3rdparty** used as a depend project for **Project B** and in **Project B** pom.xml file i have added below lines

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pre.cdd.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-3rdparty</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now i am using Artifactory for dependency management and added  **common-3rdparty** project into Artifactory but now when i am running `mvn eclipse:eclipse`  project build successful but  **common-3rdparty.jar** not downloaded so **Project B** giving exception

> common-3rdparty.jar missing

So it mean somehow **common-3rdparty.jar** not downloaded from Artifactory . What i am doing wrong here?

**EDIT:-**

Now my simple question is that if i have 10 project and 9 project needed to run 10th one so we added 9 dependencies in 10th project pom.xml now what changes i have to do in Artifactory side or pom file so it will easily get depended projects.

Comment: How your Maven is configured to work with Artifactory? Which repositories it is resolving from? To which repository did you deploy the `common-3rdparty.jar` and how did you deploy it?

Comment: I made changes settings.xml and added espository url...common-3rdparty.jar is a project i ceated jar and added in artifactory bcz it is used by another project

Comment: Which URL did you add to Maven settings? 
How did you add the jar to Artifactory? By using the UI deploy screen? By using Maven deploy command? Did you use Artifactory Maven plugin?

Comment: in Maven setting.xml created by Artifactory and replaced the Maven/conf/setting.xml file. Artifactory have deploy tab added jar by that.

Comment: Which Artifactory URL did you use in settings.xml file? What is the link that you can now download the jar file from the tree browser in the UI (I need to verify that you deployed the file correctly)

Comment: URL is <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/remote-repos</url>

Comment: I want all the dependent project should automatically work for main project which previously working it automatically creating jar file of related project and added in main project lib. Now i added artifactory and dependency of projects are not working

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml of common-3rdparty project?

Comment: that contains only third party dependency jar nothing else

Answer (score 2):

The `remote-repos` contain only the remote repositories (hence the name). If you deployed the jar into Artifactory yourself, it resides in one of the local repositories, that's why maven can't find it. You should use `lib-releses` instead of `remote-repos` in your maven configuration.

Comment: So if i will use lib-releses it will download jar from Maven,Jboss,GoogleCode repo as well? becuase these repo also added in Atifactory

Comment: you can examine which repositories a certain artifact resolves from in the main screen when focusing on artifact. If you're an admin, you can examine `lib-releases` virtual repository configuration and see what it includes. By default it includes the `remote-repos` which means it will resolve from the repositories you mentioned.